# change default collation in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

It seems to me that phpMyAdmin imports tables by default with collation latin1_swedish_ci, how i change this?

Comment: [This answer shows how to change it from phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719854/731314).

Comment: @Gary It does not, it only shows how to change collation on existing database.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your Mysql configuration change the default-character-set operative under the [mysqld] tab. For example:

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Don't forget to restart your Mysql server afterwards for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This is not valid in debian's 5.5.28-1-log, default-character-set is invalid value.

Comment: The above solution did not work, I did this instead: `[mysqld] character-set-server=utf8 collation-server=utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 21):

**For Linux:**

1. You need to have access to the MySQL config file.
   The location can vary from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to `~/my.cnf` (user directory).
2. Add the following lines in the section `[mysqld]`:

   ```
   collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
   character_set_server=utf8
   ```
3. Restart the server:

   ```
   service mysqld restart
   ```

Answer (score 14):

This is not a phpMyAdmin question.

Collations are part of recent MySQL releases, you must set the default collation of the server (or at least of the database) to change that behaviour.

To convert already imported tables to UTF-8 you can do (in PHP):

```
$dbname = 'my_databaseName';
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE `$dbname` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `$dbname`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
   $query = "ALTER TABLE {$dbname}.`{$row[0]}` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
   mysql_query($query);
   $query = "ALTER TABLE {$dbname}.`{$row[0]}` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
   mysql_query($query);
}
echo 'all tables converted';
```

Code snippet taken from [here](http://jonas.elunic.de/blog/index.php/2006/07/26/mysql-datenbank-zu-utf8-konventieren/).

Answer (score 13):

For `utf8mb4`, add/change the following in the `[mysqld]` section:

```
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server = utf8mb4
```

Then restart the `mysql` service (for Ubuntu the command is `sudo service mysql restart`)

Comment: From [their document](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/) on **Example: Changing the Default Character Set To UTF-8**, they use `collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `character-set-server = utf8mb4` under `[mysqld]` group. The difference is `-` and `_` but I don't know did they all work on all OS or not but I use `-` and it work fine. Up voted.

Answer (score 9):

know this is an old post. But the way i changed the default charset through phpMyAdmin was:

phpMyadmin main page > Variables tab (Server variables and settings) > searched for "character" and changed all variables from "latin1" to "utf8".
(on a MAMP installation with phpMyAdmin v. 3.5.7)

And as the others said, this is the variables for MySQL and not some phpMyAdmin specific ones.

Comment: It lives until the next WAMP restart. How can I save these settings?

Comment: I was using MAMP when answering this question, not sure if MAMP and WAMP are configured the same way. But I don't use those installations anymore, I make it from scratch.. Maybe someone else can help??

Comment: Just got Windows again, an ran into above problem as well, where wamp reset the config on restart. I solved this by following the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14194212/900774

Answer (score 5):

MySQL DB « change [Collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) Name of a Database|Table to `utf8_general_ci` inorder to support Unicode.

Change **Configuration settings** file also

---

XAMPP: 
uncomment `UTF 8 Settings` from the Configuration settings file « `D:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`

```config
## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
```

---

For MySQL server to support UTF8 and the below line of code in file `my.cnf`

```config
## UTF 8 Settings
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

---

@see

- [XAMPP - Apache Virtual Host Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48404726/5081877)
- [XAMPP security concept - Error 403,404](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48380154/5081877)

Answer (score 4):

1. Insert this strings into `my.ini` (or `my.cnf`)

```
[mysqld]
collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

2. Add into `config.inc.php`

```php
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

3. You need to restart **MySQL** server and remove cookies,data for domain where is located **PhpMyAdmin**
4. Reload page with **PhpMyAmdin** and at look the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The original question was for the **default setting in phpMyAdmin.**
I think the question relates to creating a NEW database in phpMyAdmin - when the page shows utf8mb4...
This IS a phpMyAdmin setting!
If you want the default for creating new databases to show utf8_general_ci.
Add the following 2 line to your config.inc.php file:

`$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf8';`

`$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';`

See phpMyAdmin docs https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html and
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_DefaultConnectionCollation

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use utf8mb4 instead, and the configuration had to be the following:

```
collation_server = utf8mb4_general_ci
character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

the server would not start if the character_set was set to `utf8`