# MySQL to php charset issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I suppose it's common trouble, so, what i have:
DB schema with table, containing INTs and VARCHARS of utf8 - ut8_unicode_ci, and this:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jdmdb";
?>
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Tуpe" сontent="tехt/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>JDM Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or     die("Не удаётся подключиться: </br>". mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("хуй: </br>".          mysql_error());

    $query = ('select * from cars where id="'.$_GET['c1'].'";');
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    ?>
    <table border=1><tr>
    <?
        while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_row(($result))){
        echo '<td>'.$result_row[1].'</td><td>'.$result_row[2].'</td><td>'.$result_row[3].'</td><td>'.$result_row[4].'</td><td>'.$result_row[5].'</td><td>'.$result_row[6].'</td><td>'.$result_row[7].'</td><td>'.$result_row[8].'</td><td>'.$result_row[9].'</td><td>'.$result_row[10].'</td><td>'.$result_row[11].'</td><td>'.$result_row[12].'</td><td>'.$result_row[13].'</td><td>'.$result_row[14].'</td><td>'.$result_row[15].'</td><td>'.$result_row[16].'</td><td>'.$result_row[17].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>'; 
    }?>
    </table>
    <?
    mysql_close($connection);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and what i recieve:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: You need to [stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) as they are removed in PHP7

Comment: As @Machavity say do not use the mysql_functions. Try to set the collation for the utf type yo wish to use directly in the database.

Comment: You're very vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: What text _should_ you be getting?  (I need to work backward.)  Please provide it in a way I can 'copy', not in a screen image.

Comment: You may have to convert your code from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to set character to utf-8.

1. While creating the table with phpMyAdmin, select `utf8_unicode_ci`
2. Add `mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8′")` when you're accessing the database.
3. Set utf-8 in html tag: `meta charset="utf-8"`
4. Check character encoding in both your browser & text editor.
5. In MySQL, change the setting in `my.cnf`.

I think the problem is `my.cnf`, and here is the  tutorial about how to change it.

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

> To set the default to UTF-8, you want to add the following to my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

If you're using something like xampp, wamp, etc.

Read this: [How can I change my MySQL collation in WAMPSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473531/how-can-i-change-my-mysql-collation-in-wampserver)

Find `my.ini` in `X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\my.ini`

(what ever you use, it will be in your MySQL directory.)

***Updated at 2018/NOV/06***

In PHP7, mysql has been removed.
Like @Rick James said, for db connection, better use mysqli or PDO.

[PHP manual - mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> Warning - This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

[mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Comment: Do not mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`, use only the latter.

Comment: `init-connect` is ignored by `root`.