# converting text field from latin1_swedish to utf8?

Tags: mysql, unicode, collections, utf-8

Hi guys is there a safe way to convert a table from latin1_swedish to fully utf8?

Someone can explain me which are the steps to safely do it?

(maybe using phpmyadmin dunno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Grab [Sqlyog Community Edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/).
- **Make a backup of your database.**
- Press F6 on the tables you need to edit.
- Disable the "Hide Language Options" checkmark in the bottom right if needed.
- Change the `charset` and `collation` as needed.

I am not sure of any specific pitfalls in changing to/from utf8, but the backup should serve you well should anything go wrong.

Comment: i am not sure i can install software on production server :(. Are there any way to do it with phpmyadmin?

Comment: I'm not familiar with phpmyadmin but check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153706/change-default-collation-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: ok thanks here the queries:
mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE `$dbname` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");

$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `$dbname`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
   $query = "ALTER TABLE {$dbname}.`{$row[0]}` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
   mysql_query($query);
   $query = "ALTER TABLE {$dbname}.`{$row[0]}` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";

Answer (score 0):

I assume **latin1_swedish_ci** is default collation of your database server. In such case i use the following collations:

- Database: defaults (latin1 & latin1_swedish_ci)
- Table: defaults (latin1 & latin1_swedish_ci)
- Column: utf8 & utf8_unicode_ci whenever needed defaults (latin1 & latin1_swedish_ci) otherwise.

There can be number of solutions to this problem, but the following solution worked for me in some worst case scenarios too.

Steps:

1. Copy the structure to new table.
2. Change the charset & collation of
   table fields to **utf8** &
   **utf8_unicode_ci** respectively as
   needed.
3. Fill the new table with data in old table, using **CONVERT**.

   --Copy table structure

   CREATE TABLE `table_name` LIKE `old_table_name`;

   --Change collations as you like

   ALTER TABLE `table_name`

   CHANGE `column_name1` `column_name1` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,

   CHANGE `column_name2` `column_name2` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL;

   -- Import the data

   INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`,`column_name1`,`column_name2`,`column_name3`)

   SELECT `id`,

   CONVERT(CONVERT(_latin1 `column_name1` USING binary) USING utf8) collate utf8_unicode_ci,

   CONVERT(CONVERT(_latin1 `column_name2` USING binary) USING utf8) collate utf8_unicode_ci,

   `column_name3`

   FROM `old_table_name`