# Set default collation phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change the default collation in phpmyadmin so that when I create a table, the collation of the columns is utf8_unicode_ci.  I have tried the following and it does not work.

```
[mysqld]
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
```

The columns still default to latin1_swedish_ci.  Any ideas?

PHPmyadmin 3.5.2
MySQL 5.1.44

Comment: By the way, I DID restart MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Log into phpMyAdmin.
Select your database from the list on the left.
Click on "Operations" from the top set of tabs.
In the Collation box, choose your new collation from the dropdown menu, then click go.

Comment: Who voted this answer up ?? The question is how to set the Default. This answer says how to change an existing database.

Comment: The question is how to change the default for new tables in a database. This answer addresses that question. This is different than changing the default collation for new databases, which will not affect the collation for new tables in an existing database.