# access forbidden xampp in mac php

Tags: php, macos

there is the error infomation:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I have setting httpd.conf file as follw:

```css
Alias /myspace "/volumes/myspace/workspace/phpworkspace"
<Directory "/volumes/myspace/workspace/phpworkspace">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    #Require all granted
</Directory>
```

"/volumes/myspace/workspace/phpworkspace" this place is my location of code. I have tried many methods:

1. [Xampp Access Forbidden php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php)
2. [New xampp security concept: Access Forbidden Error 403 - Windows 7 - phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Where the "httpd.conf" file is located?

Answer (score 2):

I have solve the problem .

### in file "httpd.conf",there has another default Directory configuation like follow:

```css
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

you can delete this directory or change is as follow:

```css
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Where the "httpd.conf" file is located?

Comment: This answer fixed my problem too. @AlirezaAkbari open XAMPP application go to Volumes tab and mount lampp directory. Explore it then its in the etc folder. 
There was a default Directory configuration which blocks my connections.

Answer (score 1):

The `Order` directive should be `Allow` first, then `Deny`.
Set `Allow from all` and don't set anything for `Deny`.

Change your `Directory` directive to this and it should work

```
<Directory "/volumes/myspace/workspace/phpworkspace">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    #Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: thank you very mach ,but it doesn`t work for me . I was suspect if there has some problem with my file permisson. all my files in  "workspace" is: user- "write and read" , admin- readonly  ,everyone- readonly. is file permission can affact access?