# Laravel routes do not work at all

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, laravel-5

My laravel routes are not working at all. I tried something like this:

```
Route::get('welcome', function () {
    return View::make('welcome');
});
```

Accessing it with localhost/project/project/public/welcome works fine. I have tried it in many ways but seems like routes aren't working since localhost/project/welcome show me 404 error. I know there is simillar topic but there is no answer for me. Could somebody help me out please?

My htaccess file looks like this (I have never touched it):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your HTTP server to have the document root as project/project/public/

For example in Apache you can do something like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                                                            
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/project/public/
```

And in Nginx it will like that:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/project/project/public/;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it just httpd.conf file?

Comment: Depends on your server configuration. You will probably find it under /etc/apache2/sites-available or /etc/nginx/sites-available

Comment: I am using xampp, will search for it

Comment: for XAMPP I think it's httpd.conf

Comment: Oh something happend finally, but I dont have permission to open this page now XD

Comment: ERROR 403 access forbidden: you do not have access to this object it is secured or server cannot load it

Comment: What is the URL you are using now? Probably, it's about accessing local. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin

Comment: Now I am using this `http://localhost/project/welcome`. Already tried that from this post but doesnt help :(

Comment: Why /boh/welcome. Your route is listening to /welcome directly. Would you try it please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95873/discussion-between-mina-youssef-and-divhelper11).

Comment: localhost/welcome  -this way right? Still access forbidden what the hell :D now everything is forbidden haha

Comment: That's XAMPP, would you share your httpd.conf, I am not XAMPP expert, but may be we can spot something.

Answer (score 1):

You have said that you can access your laravel app throught
`localhost/project/project/public/welcome`. This is because this path is your starting root path, from where you start your application.

Example that will allow you to access new route

```
Route::get('other_route', function () {
    return View::make('welcome');;
});
```

This code can be accessed, if you will type `localhost/project/project/public/other_route` into your browser

`localhost/project/welcome` won't work because your application is deeper than this path.

You should setup virutal host for your application so that your path could be `myapp.local/welcome`
`myapp.local/other_route`

Or access your application, assuming that your start point is `http://localhost/project/project/public/`

Comment: I thought that in laravel everything in url after slash `/` is in the public folder. Thats what i need actually. To make the public folder my starting point in url

Comment: If i understood your question right, it is your web server misconfiguration, not laravel issue

Comment: Oh I was sure that i need to config it from the inside of laravel project. There are server settings etc

Comment: you can start laravel's php web server, typing command `php artisan serve` in your OS console from your application root, and you will be able to run your project from http://localhost:8000/