# Error 403 - XAMPP with angular project

Tags: angularjs, apache, xampp, http-status-code-403

I used to run my angular project using `grunt serve`

Now I need it to run on my XAMPP so I installed it into my `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

But I am getting a 403 denied access even after changing my `httpd-xampp.conf`

to Require all granted as written also on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin)

I restarted my Apache as well.

What else am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `httpd-xampp.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Please these steps:

1. Do you have read permission on you angular project folder.
2. Make sure you have given document path to your index.html
   For Ex:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

For this index.html should be inside html folder.

3. Little bit of chance to fail your assets files required by an angular application. Make sure all assert files are loaded.