# localhost/xampp/ or http://localhost/index.php can't be accessed

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am learning server and sql. So I need to install xampp. But unfortunately my localhost/index.php  and localhost/xampp not working. I read many questions here stackoverflow but none solved my problem. Here is my httpd-xampp.conf file:

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all denied
<Files "php-cgi.exe">
      Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler cgi-script
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler None
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
<IfModule php7_module>
    <Files "status.php">
        php_admin_flag safe_mode off
    </Files>
</IfModule>
AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
    Options +Indexes
    <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
        DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
        DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
        DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
        DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
        DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
    </IfModule>
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>

Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"[enter image description here][1]
<Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
    <IfModule php7_module>
        <Files "webalizer.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

This is what I got when I tried to access localhost/xampp/ and           localhost/index.php

[The image is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8atw.png)

Please suggest solution:)

Comment: Almost exact problem was asked here, so you can refer to it.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score -1):

Try paste this url in your preferred website.

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs
```

And you can open the full folder in the website 
[View the screenshot, of how it shows, in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrkI6.png)

And you can access your intended file.