# How to import sql on xampp phpmyadmin via network

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, xampp

Good day. I would like to seek for help regarding importing a .sql file on phpmyadmin on xampp. I can access my phpmyadmin via network however when I'm trying to import a .sql file it doesn't connect to the server. Export is possible.

[image]

This is my settings of the `http-xampp.conf` on xampp

```
<Directory "F:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Require local
    Require ip 10.10.10.100
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try this? [New xampp security concept: Access Forbidden Error 403 - Windows 7 - phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666506/9532124)

Answer (score 0):

Hi common problem this is....this bug can occure from below:

1.if your importing file is more thn 250kb it won't import
2.another case is observe once inside ur file if there is any error like use database cmd and all....if its possible pls send ur error name let me see once

Thank u