# Acces forbidden to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't access to phpmyadmin via this URL :

http://51.254.205.243/phpmyadmin

it gives me this error :

[image]

I changed **Require local** to **Require all granted**  yet the error persists :

```
#<IfDefine PHP4>
#LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
#</IfDefine>
#<IfDefine PHP7>
#LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
#</IfDefine>

# We will enable it by default
#<IfDefine PHP>
   LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
#</IfDefine>

LoadModule perl_module        modules/mod_perl.so

Alias /phpmyadmin "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"

# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# since LAMPP 1.0RC1
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4

XBitHack on

# since 0.9.8 we've mod_perl
<IfModule mod_perl.c>
        AddHandler perl-script .pl
    PerlHandler ModPerl::PerlRunPrefork
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
        PerlSendHeader On
</IfModule>

# demo for mod_perl responsehandler
#PerlModule Apache::CurrentTime
#<Location /time>
#      SetHandler modperl
#      PerlResponseHandler Apache::CurrentTime
#</Location>

# AcceptMutex sysvsem is default but on some systems we need this
# thanks to jeff ort for this hint
#AcceptMutex flock
#LockFile /opt/lampp/logs/accept.lock

# this makes mod_dbd happy - oswald, 02aug06
# mod_dbd doesn't work in Apache 2.2.3: getting always heaps of "glibc detected *** corrupted double-linked list" on shutdown - oswald, 10sep06
#DBDriver sqlite3
```

If you have a clue about which configuration I should do to make it accessible I would be pleased.

Best

Comment: please see this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried all these things but still cannot access to it

Comment: after change config !!! restart service !? do it ?

Comment: yes I did restart apache2