# Can't find XAMPP's httpd-xampp.conf file on MacOs Mojave

Tags: php, macos, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm experiencing the problem discussed in this thread: [New xampp security concept: Access Forbidden Error 403 - Windows 7 - phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin)

To solve it I apparently need to make some changes to the httpd-xampp.conf file. I however don't know how to locate it.

Answer (score 9):

Are you guys sure you mounted /lampp?

[XAMPP Volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjdYG.png)

If not, please do so.

Then open file at

> lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

and edit it at line 20 and add a new one at 42 like this:

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
Require all granted
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

and

```
# <Location /time>
SetHandler modperl
PerlResponseHandler Apache::CurrentTime
Require all granted
```

Start XAMPP again (mounting of lampp not necessary anymore) and you are good to go.

Comment: Also, you need to restart the server. For me, I just close xamp and then restarted it. It work fine for me !

Answer (score 1):

use find command to know the location of httpd-xampp.conf. enter the following command:

```
$ sudo find / -iname "httpd-xampp.conf"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't find it.

Comment: @brightshadow can you please share a screenshot of your terminal with the output of that command?

Answer (score 0):

Is not that located at: `etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` ?

If not, then just create it, and in the main **.conf** file (`httpd.conf`)  file, insert such line:

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

Comment: No. I don't have an /etc/extra folder. I do have an /etc/appache2/extra folder. But it isn't in there. A lot of other .conf files are though.

Comment: Okay. I've done this. What code should I write in the httpd-xampp.conf file? Or can I copy someone's healthy file?

Answer (score 0):

It is located in the virtual machine running xampp, not the physical hard drive. That being said, I cannot find mine either and am simply using http://localhost:8080 to access phpMyAdmin until I find httpd-xampp.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Having issues setting up xampp on macOs or accessing the config.inc.php or httpd-xampp.conf file.
Note: For macos xampp making use virtual machine under the hood to mount the folder structure on your system.

step 1: you need to follow the instruction step by step on the screen below,
it has image illustration  which helps alot
https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html

step 2: Click on network tab within the xampp interface then enable one of the
host machine.

step3:  Click on the volume tab within the xampp interface then click on mount
then click Explore to have access to the xampp folder or files likes of config.inc.php or httpd-xampp.conf