# New xampp security concept: Access Forbidden Error 403 - Windows 7 - phpMyAdmin with latest version of xampp 7.2.12

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have downloaded and installed XAMPP 7.2.12 for Windows on Windows 7 Ultimate. I have set up XAMPP to run.

All good so far, my PHP sites run locally and everything except phpMyAdmin is available from the XAMPP menu.

However when I try to access phpMyAdmin I get this error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> New XAMPP security concept:
>
> Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.
>
> This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New xampp security concept: Access Forbidden Error 403 - Windows 7 - phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin)

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]. But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Update your XAMPP files:
Windows: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
- Require all granted
+ Require local
+ ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

source:https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20160224.html